# How to store the values of rows in php variables using mysqli?

Tags: php

I wanted to store the values returned from the sql query into php variables. For ex. I have a **query** `SELECT codes from subjects`, it returns `five rows` like:-

```
codes
-------
DA5010  
DA5020  
DA5034  
DA5032  
DA5023
```

How can I store these five values in five php variable using mysqli.

I have tried this but it's not working

```
$sql = "SELECT code FROM subjects";
$results = $result->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch_row())
{
 $v1 = $row[0]; 
 $v2 = $row[1]; 
 $v3 = $row[2];
 $v4 = $row[3]; 
 $v5 = $row[4]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and how it failed?

Comment: I have posted the code that I have tried.

Comment: If all 5 values are not in one row your assignment will not work

Comment: $row is going to be an array with ONE value in it - `code` from ONE record of your results. you're not going to have row[1], row[2], etc... you're not fetching that many fields.

Comment: See, suspecting 5 rows, you could use a for-loop to iterate, instead of the while, then switch over the incremented value and assign variables. You seem to lack basic understanding of control structures and data structures.

Comment: As Far I Know, Mr @Fred-ii- is having *super power* to close this question.

Comment: @NanaPartykar hehe, only if I knew "which" one to close it with ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get one row from the result set each time round the while loop so your code will only remember that last row because you are overwriting the variables each time round the loop

You could store the data in an array like this

```
$sql = "SELECT code FROM subjects";
$results = $result->query($sql);
$data = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $row['code'];
}
```

or invent your new vaiables like this

```
$sql = "SELECT code FROM subjects";
$results = $result->query($sql);
$i = 1;
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    ${"v" . $i} = $row['code'];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each value is in a different row, so your loop needs to be something like this:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    ${"v" . $i} = $row['code'];
    $i++;
}
```

We use `${}` to create variable names to store each value in. Now you can `echo $v1;` or any of the other variables or re-use them as you need.